# android CountDownTimer формат Hh:MM:ss

Tags: android, android-studio, таймер, countdowntimer

```
 new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) { //Sets 10 second remaining

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            textView.setText("" + String.format("%d:%d",
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }
```

в пременной milliseconds хранится время в милесекундах до определенного события 
в textView выводит время 92:48 а хотелось бы что бы выводил 1:32:48 т.е хотелось бы добавить часы 
зарание благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет этот класс: [`android.text.format.DateUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)

```
    textView.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
```

Comment: получается 950 часов показывает таймер мой вариант работает нормально тока вот не показывает часы показывает минуты 90 минут это должно быть 1:30 на таймере

Comment: Метод принимает время в секундах - миллисекунды надо делить на 1000 или как у Вас `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)`

Comment: поделил на 1000 все заработало  )

Answer (score 1):

Для преобразования текущего времени (в миллисекундах) в часы, минуты и секунды я использовал класс Calendar. Как то так:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int mHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int mMinutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int mSec = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: не понимаю как это скормить CountDownTimer что бы отображать обратный отсчет

Answer (score 0):

Вот подробнее про [TimeUnit](http://www.aboutme.by/2012/11/timeunit.html)  .Там расписано как получать минуты , часы , дни !

Comment: можно ли пример кода для CountDownTimer